# Upload large file to Cloud Service in Web Api

Tags: asp.net, azure, file-upload, asp.net-web-api, azure-storage

After read below posts.

1. [How to increase the temp folder size of web role](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kwill/archive/2011/07/18/how-to-increase-the-size-of-the-windows-azure-web-role-asp-net-temporary-folder.aspx?Redirected=true).
2. [Too small temp folder size of web role](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh134851.aspx).

I understood there is a limitation for uploading large file to cloud service. And seems like windows azure doesn't allocate large size of space for web role by default.

So I was trying to find a way to break it. One of the ways I have been testing successfully is grasp the stream of post request and read it through block by block without reading it from the temp folder. Below is what I done. please review it .

```
CloudBlobClient blobClient = CreateBlobClient(account);

BlobRequestOptions options = CreateBlobRequestOpt();

CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(sContainerName);
bool b = container.CreateIfNotExist();
CloudBlob blob = container.GetBlobReference(sBlobName);

blob.UploadFromStream(postFileStream, options);
```

I just passed the `postFileStream` which I got from `Request.Files[0].InputStream` in the controller of `Asp.net MVC` to the CloudBlobClient. and the `CloudBlobClient` which from `Azure Storage Library SDK` will read the stream block by block. In this way this will support the large file post. In my test. Even the 2GB file can works fine.

But I also want to make it work in the `Asp.net Web Api`. and I found the `Request` in Api controller is `System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage`. It is different from the one in MVC controller named with `System.Web.HttpRequestBase`.  So How can I get the post request file stream in Web Api Controller like in the MVC controller? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can get file content(s) using `Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync()` method.
You can try something like this:

```
        IEnumerable<HttpContent> contents = Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(new MultipartMemoryStreamProvider()).Result.Contents;
        foreach (var content in contents)
        {
            //...
            //create your blob object...
            //...
            blob.UploadFromStream(content.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result);
        }
```